# How to use the text value of a formula as the name of the tab you try to reference to in another formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-online

I have this workbook to make invoices using data from the crm. In one sheet I have all the invoice names with hyperlinks to the respective sheets (sheet for every invoice) called Index. In another sheet i have a summary of all the invoices with invoicenumber, client number etc etc. That sheet takes the invoicenames via a reference to the Index (Index!D7 for example) which returns the name of one the sheets. My problem is that I need to extract the data from every individual invoice sheet to have data for the summary. Because every line summariseses a different invoice and it is too much work to manually change the formula for the invoice name, i want to be able to copy paste the formula. For that reason I want to use the data I get from the index file (index!d7) in a new formula. =ALS($C8=0;"";'AON_xxxxxx-xx'!$E$14) is the current formula for every line, and the AON_xxxxxx-xx is the sheet name of the invoice, and also the data retrieved from the index file. I want to swap that for a formula to make sure i wont have to do it manually for every invoice. Anyone has any idea? By the way, i am using excel online. Thanks in advance!

I tried changing =ALS($C8=0;"";'AON_xxxxxx-xx'!$E$14) to =ALS($C8=0;"";(Index!D7)!$E$14) or =ALS($C8=0;"";(C8)!$E$14) but i couldt get it to work

Comment: You would need to use the INDIRECT() formula: `=ALS($C8=0;"";INDIRECT("'"&Index!D7&"'!$E$14"))`